# Bad Operand Types for Binary Operator ">"?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am writing a BST Program. I get the error:

"Bad Operand Types for Binary Operator ">"

first type: java.lang.Object

second type: java.lang.Object"

This is the method where it gives me the error:

```
public void placeNodeInTree(TreeNode current, TreeNode t)                                                                    
{   
    if(current == null)
        current = t;
    else{
       if(current.getValue() > t.getValue()) 
            current.setRight(t);
       if(current.getValue() < t.getValue()) 
            current.setLeft(t);  
        }
}
```

getValue() has a return type of Object, thus the java.lang.Object types. This is the first time I have ever seen this error. Can anyone give me some background on this error? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that these Objects only have the "Object" parent in common? If so, there is no real comparision to be made. Try and find the real type of the class (e.g. using instanceof) and try to compare them afterwards. Or try and refactor getValue() to make sure it returns something that uses [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 6):

Sure - you simply can't apply the `>` operator between objects. What would you expect it to do? You can't apply any of the other binary operators either - `+`, `-`, `/` etc (with the exception of string concatenation).

Ideally, you should make your `TreeNode` *generic*, and either have a `Comparator<T>` which is able to compare any two instances, or make `T extend Comparable<T>`. Either way, you can then compare them with:

```
int comparisonResult = comparator.compare(current.getValue(), t.getValue());
if (comparisonResult > 0) {
  // current "greater than" t
} else if (comparisonResult < 0) {
  // current "less than" t
} else {
  // Equal
}
```

or

```
int comparisonResult = current.getValue().compareTo(t.getValue());
// Code as before
```

Without generics you *could* cast the values to `Comparable` or still use a general `Comparator`... but generics would be a better bet.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in another way?

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't support operator overloading, so the `<` operator is not defined for non-primitive types. You probably want to use the `Comparable<T>` interface instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare objects using `>` or `<`. You need to compare them using some method, like compareTo (which you need to implement).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare two arbitraty objects with the `>` operator. The `>` operator can only be used (directly) on primitive integer types.

You could make the objects you intend to compare implement interface `java.lang.Comparable`, and then call the `compareTo` method on them to compare them.

```
Comparable left = (Comparable)current.getValue();
Comparable right = (Comparable)t.getValue();

if (left.compareTo(right) > 0)
    current.setRight(t);

// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of equals only cares about reference equality.  An object does not know if Cat is greater than Apple nor would it care.  You should provide a concrete implementation that overrides both equals and hashcode as well as implements the Comparable interface.  This will allow you to determine if in fact Cat is greater than Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can just use another primitive variables like

```
int temp=(int)current.getValue();
```

Comment: Can `java.lang.Object` be cast onto  `int`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about using `<` to compare two `Object` types. Regardless, this question seems to have already been answered nearly 10 years ago.